# Как в three.js сделать все модели одинакового размера?

Tags: three.js

У меня есть несколько моделей(геометрий) И все они разного размера и формата

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var materials = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "red"}) ;
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
scene.add(cube);


var topy = 'models/JSON/111.json';
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
      loader.load(
        topy,
        function ( obj ) {           
         scene.add( obj ); 
      });

            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var normal = loader.load( 'models/3ds/portalgun/textures/normal.jpg' );
            var loader = new THREE.TDSLoader( );
            loader.setResourcePath( 'models/3ds/portalgun/textures/' );
            loader.load( 'models/3ds/portalgun/portalgun.3ds', function ( object ) {
                object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                        child.material.normalMap = normal;
                    }
                } );
                scene.add( object );
            } );

            var loader = new THREE.ThreeMFLoader();
            loader.load( 'models/3MF/Mi-24.3mf', function ( object ) {
                scene.add( object );
            } );
```

Мне необходимо чо бы все модели выводились одного размера и в одном и том же месте

так как у меня есть пол на котором в центре должны выводится модели

```
var floor_gam = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ) ;
var floor_rotat = - Math.PI / 2;
var mat_standart = new  THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x808080, roughness: 0, metalness: 0 } ) ; 

var  object_floor_standart = new THREE.Mesh( floor_gam, mat_standart );
object_floor_standart.rotation.x = floor_rotat ;
object_floor_standart.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(  object_floor_standart );
```

Кто не будь знает как можно это сделать?
Я пробовал

```
 var center = obj.geometry.boundingSphere.center;
 controls.target.set( center.x, center.y, center.z );
```

Но это работает не со всеми моделями 
и просто подгоняет камеру к модели а нужно наоборот

Comment: Имеется в виду одинаковыми по высоте?

Comment: @prisoner849 Да можно и по высоте.  В идеале что-то на подобие  `width: 300px; height: 300px; object-fit: contain; ` только для three.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, функция для умещения объекта в заданные размеры (`scaleToFit()`). В данном случае, максимальный размер утенка по оси x.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 3, 8);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.0));

var sizeBound = new THREE.Vector3(4, 4, 4);

var b = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(sizeBound.x, sizeBound.y, sizeBound.z), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
var boxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(b);
scene.add(boxHelper);

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf", (gltf) => {

  scaleToFit(gltf.scene, sizeBound); // умещаем в заданные размеры

  let b = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(gltf.scene);
  gltf.scene.position.sub(b.getCenter()); // центрируем
  gltf.scene.position.y -= (sizeBound.y - b.getSize().y) * 0.5; // опускаем к "полу"
  
  scene.add(gltf.scene); // добавляем в сцену
});

function scaleToFit(obj, bound) {
  let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
  let size = new THREE.Vector3();
  box.getSize(size);
  let vScale = new THREE.Vector3().copy(bound).divide(size);
  let scale = Math.min(vScale.x, Math.min(vScale.y, vScale.z));
  obj.scale.setScalar(scale);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

Comment: `scaleToFit()` у меня работает только с GLTF форматом я попытался адаптировать его под разные форматы но не получилось `var loader = new THREE.AWDLoader();loader.load("./models/AWD/simple.awd", (gltf) =>{
  scaleToFit(gltf.scene, sizeBound); 
  gltf.scene.position.sub(new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(gltf.scene).getCenter());scene.add(gltf.scene); 
}); var loader = new THREE.AWDLoader(); loader.load( 'models/AWD/simple.awd', function (trunk ) {
scaleToFit(trunk.scene, sizeBound); trunk.scene.position.sub(new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(trunk.scene).getCenter());
scene.add(trunk.scene); });`

Comment: ошибка `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateMatrixWorld' of undefined`

Comment: Разные лоадеры возвращают разные объекты. Функция принимает в первом параметре объект, наследованный от `THREE.Object3D()`. Поэтому надо смотреть, что передаете в функцию - можно передать меш, либо сцену целиком, но передать геометрию - нельзя.

Comment: Все вроде бы разобрался `
var loader = new THREE.AWDLoader();
loader.load( 'models/AWD/simple.awd', function (trunk ) {
scaleToFit(trunk, sizeBound); // умещаем в заданные размеры
trunk.position.sub(new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(trunk).getCenter()); // центрируем
scene.add(trunk);  
} );`

Comment: Хотел еще спросить можно ли начинать не с середины а с дна куба?  http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/01/25/YVSSba3799c4e2aee5e3.jpg Просто тогда широкие модели не могут  касаться пола

Comment: @zeni1agent обновил сниппет в ответе :)

Comment: Спасибо за функцию в 90% случая она отображает модель правильно 
Но я нашел пару странных багов о которых хотел бы сообщить
в основном я использовал код из 21-25 строки

Comment: Dae: Одна модель из пяти на которых я тестировал отобразилась неправильно
http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/01/30/324a502c025a8f21cb8.jpg
Здесь скорее всего я напортачил но на всякий случай сообщу
MMD: Анимация запускается раньше чем уменьшается модель изо чего могу возникать некоторые баги
http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/01/30/tea56186601176f49f.gif

Comment: FBX: Анимация одно модели из трех у меня отобразилась некорректно
http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/01/30/dfe81c8117f2139feb4.gif
http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/01/30/dsd617a827e422f7802.jpg

Comment: Я заметил что код 21-25 работает только внутри другой функций
И изо особенностей строения кода Sea MD2 и PDB он не может вывести их

Я пытался использовать код в функций что бы ограничить модели MD2 и PDB
`function fder(){scaleToFit(character.root,sizeBound);let b=new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(character.root );character.root.position.sub(b.getCenter());character.root.position.y-=(sizeBound.y-b.getSize().y)* 0.5;}fder() `
Ошибки исчезли как и модель написано что она вывелась а самой модели в сцене нет

Comment: В основном я экспериментировал на примера с https://threejs.org/examples/